# Mockito: How to mock a method with Mono<> with doOnError and doFinally

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, webclient, junit5

Below is the webclient call for which I need to write jUnit tests

```
webclient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .headers(headersConsumer -> getHeaders())
                .bodyValue(requestObject)
                .exchangeToMono( response -> {
                    if(response.statusCode().isError()) {
                        log.error(new StringMapMessage()
                                .with("info", "error")
                                .with("responseTime", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis())
                                .with("responseStatus", response.statusCode()));
                    }
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class);})
                .doOnError(error -> log.error("Encountered webclient exception while Publishing to Reporting API endpoint. ErrorMessage: {}", error.getMessage()))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(1000)).filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof TimeoutException))
                .doFinally(response ->
                        log.info(new StringMapMessage()
                            .with("info", "completed ")
                            .with("responseTime", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis())));
```

how to cover the doFinally block as it is not getting executed in the test.
It is not getting covered in the sonar coverage.

below is the test written for it.

```
        @Test
    public void someMethod_Success()
    {
        Mono<String> strMono = Mono.just("Single Item Only");

        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
        when(requestBodySpec.bodyValue(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        ClientResponse clientResponse = ClientResponse
                .create(HttpStatus.OK)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                body(strMono.toString()).build();
        doAnswer(new Answer() {
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                ((Function<ClientResponse, ? extends Mono>) args[0]).apply(clientResponse);
                return Mono.just(strMono);
            }
        }).when(requestHeadersSpec).exchangeToMono(any(Function.class));

        RequestObject requestObject = RequestObject .builder().build();
        class.SomeMethod(requestObject );
    }
```